# Test for convexity

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the online learning setting where instantaneous loss is given by
\begin{equation}
\ell_t(f_t;(\mathbf{x}_t,y_t))=\max \left( {0,\left( \left( {\frac{N}{P}} \right){I_{(y_t = 1)}} + \left( {\frac{{P - F_n}}{P}} \right){I_{(y_t =  - 1)}}\right)  - y_t f_t({\bf x}_t) } \right) 
\end{equation}

where $\ell_t$ is instantaneous loss at time $t$; $({\bf x}_t,y_t) \subseteq R^n \times \{-1,+1\}$ is instance-label pair. $N$ and $P$ denote the count of negative and positive instances respectively and and $F_n$ is no. of false negatives so far.

Can somebody tell me if the loss function is convex?

Comment: Convex in what? Which quantities are fixed and which are variable? And what is $f_t()$?

Comment: convexity in $f_t$ is required. Assume $f_t(w)=w^T x_t$, a binary classifier. Upto  time $t$, I have calculated $N, P$ and $F_n$, so they are fixed at time $t$.

Comment: And $x$ and $y$? Both variable?

Comment: yes.  at time $t$, I have seen both $x_t$ and $y_t$.

Comment: So the variable is $w$?

Comment: Correct. In the eq., you can take $f_t(x_t)=w^Tx_t$, $w \in R^n$

Comment: Then yes, it is convex in $w$!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26716/discussion-between-chandresh-and-michael-grant).